# How to initialize multiprocessing.Array inside of a process and use it in another processes?

Tags: python, arrays, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

What is the best way to initialize Array inside of one process and make it so it is shared among other processes? I was thinking maybe initializing it inside of Process1 and then broadcasting it to other processes. Would that work? Or does queue only pass value? I am a bit confused with Python's way of sharing variables among processes.

For example:

```py
from multiprocessing import Array, Lock, Manager, Process, Value
import time

a = Array('i', [0])

def f(t):
    print(a[0])
    time.sleep(t)
    a[0] += 1
    print(a[0])

p1 = Process(target=f,args=(1,))
p2 = Process(target=f,args=(2,))

p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
```

This is a normal shared Array and the program outputs 0 0 1 2. But if i do things differently like so:

```py
from multiprocessing import Array, Lock, Manager, Process, Value
import time

a = Array('i', [0])

def f(t):
    global a
    print(a[0])
    time.sleep(t)
    a = Array('i', [a[0]])
    a[0] += 1
    print(a[0])

p1 = Process(target=f,args=(1,))
p2 = Process(target=f,args=(2,))

p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
```

So I redefine Array inside of process with the same value so in theory it should output the same. But it outputs 0 0 1 1. My understanding is that because of GIL Python has to use separate processes instead of real threads so the global variables aren't actually shared. So when i redefine `a` inside of a process, it is allocated at a different position memory so now Process 1 and 2 point to different locations in memory. So my question is what is the best way to tell Process 2 that it should now use a new Array?

Comment: I believe you want *"multiprocessing shared memory" in any Python newer than around v3.8 https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html

Comment: Oh nice. This is actually really helpful. So if i get this correctly, instead of using messages to get around problems that GIL causes, this uses shared memory blocks which is way faster and easier to use.

Comment: Yes, hopefully, depending on your use case.

Comment: As an aside: `a[0] += 1` is *not* an atomic operation and so you can theoretically end up with 0 0 1 1 being printed. The code should be `with a.get_lock(): a[0] += 1`. Try `for _ in range(1_000_000): a[0] += 1` and then see what gets printed. You will probably not see a 2_000_000 printed.